# Does Magento Template.php in every block define common methods for all template belong to these module?

Tags: magento

Does Template.php in every blocks define common methods for all templates belong to these module?

I am so intresting about this. I am researching a plugin, there's a template named init.phtml where used a method defined in the /Block/Template.php. I have no idea why it can directly call $this->methodInTemplateBlock() in init.phtml. Anyone can explain to me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the method `Mage_Core_Block_Template::fetchView`, you will see the following:

```
public function fetchView($fileName)
{
    ...
    try {
        $includeFilePath = realpath($this->_viewDir . DS . $fileName);
        if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath($this->_viewDir)) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {
            include $includeFilePath;
        } else {
            Mage::log('Not valid template file:'.$fileName, Zend_Log::CRIT, null, null, true);
        }
    ...
}
```

As you can see, the contents of the template file are directly included in the body of a method living in this class, which means you can simply refer to the class instance through $this.